# How to evaluate patient significant improvement?

Tags: statistical-significance, paired-data, pre-post-comparison

Imagine the following study where we want to teach a group of $N$ patients to improve their capacity to hold their breath under the water. We have data for the patients before teaching them and after teaching them. Something like

```r
patient_id | duration before (s) | duration after (s)
-----------------------------------------------------
1          | 53                  | 78
2          | 28                  | 65
...        | ...                 | ...
N          | 67                  | 70
```

What I've seen in the literature is to report the fold increase, ie: the ratio of an increased number to the original number. For the above table it would be

```r
patient_id | duration before (s) | duration after (s) | FI
------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 53                  | 78                 | 1.47
2          | 28                  | 65                 | 2.32
...        | ...                 | ...                | ...
N          | 67                  | 70                 | 1.04
```

And the reported FI could be $FI = 1.61 \pm 0.53$.

However, I would like to compute the percentage of patients that got a significant improvement in their holding breath duration. For example, I would say that patient `N` got an insignificant improvement, since moving from 67 to 70 doesn't look like a huge advance, while patient `2` doubled their duration. My objective is to have a result like "X% of the patients showed a significant increase in their holding breath performance".

Which evaluation methodology should I use to that end?

I thought of computing the average FI and its standard deviation and then marking the patients with $FI_i < \langle FI \rangle - k \sigma$ as "not improved". However, I feel that using the same data to calculate the average fold increase and to filter the patients could lead to data leakage and bias the results.

Comment: You use the word "significant" in the sense of "functionally important."  Although statistics can help you quantify what that is, it's up to you to specify how great a relative improvement is "important."  I fear your use of "significant" is likely to mislead people into misinterpreting your question by assuming you mean this word in its conventional sense of a difference that is detectable with your data, which is a different matter altogether.  Please, then, clarify your question and include a characterization of *how much* of an improvement you would deem "significant."

Comment: By some definitions those ratios aren't "fold increases." From [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_change): 'a change from 30 to 60 is defined as a fold-change of 2. This is also referred to as a "one fold increase".' Maybe call those values the "post/pre ratio" to avoid confusion. Note that averages of ratios don't always work well to describe the distribution of outcomes. Please edit your question to say more about what might be considered an "important" improvement, as @whuber has asked: is a number of seconds improvement, reaching some duration_after, or some post/pre ratio?

Comment: @whuber With significant I meant that you can reject the null hypothesis, which is "the duration of the participant X hasn't changed"

Comment: That contradicts the ways in which employ the word "significant" in your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need repeated measurements of the patients before and after the treatment to determine if the effect is significant for a single patient. If patient N has values of 67, 66, 67 before and 70, 71, 70 after the treatment, it would probably be still significant. If you have an idea of how large this variance is, you could use the [effect size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size).

Alternatively, you could rewrite your result from:

"X% of the patients showed a **significant** increase in their holding breath performance".

to

"X% of the patients showed a increase in their holding breath performance **of at least Y%**".

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to conflate functional improvement with some type of statistical improvement.

> I would like to compute the percentage of patients that got a significant improvement in their holding breath duration... moving from 67 to 70 doesn't look like a huge advance, while patient 2 doubled their duration. My objective is to have a result like "X% of the patients showed a significant increase in their holding breath performance".

That sounds like you want something that would be significant for an individual.

The particular measure that you propose, however:

> I thought of computing the average FI* and its standard deviation and then marking the patients with $FI_i < \langle FI \rangle - k \sigma$ as "not improved".

would simply identify individuals whose measure of improvement was in some low quantile among the results of your study sample. If training was very successful, many of those in a low *quantile* of improvement could nevertheless have a *magnitude* of improvement that is functionally important for them.

You need to apply your understanding of the subject matter to decide first on a measure of functional importance. If one ever had to hold breath under water to survive, the *achieved number of seconds* or the *increase* in the number of seconds of breath-holding following training might be more functionally important than the post/pre *ratio* of breath-holding times that you propose.

A plot of the empirical distribution function of improvement scores would then describe your results nicely. A reader could decide for herself what a functionally significant improvement score would be and determine what fraction of individuals did better than that.

One caution: as others have noted, anything that you find with this particular design could not demonstrate that your "teaching" had anything to do with improved performance. It might just be that people tend to do better when they try a second time. Without a control group, for example individuals who had a second test without the training, you can't say anything about the effect of the "teaching."

---

*I'm reluctant to call the post/pre ratio a "fold increase" (FI) due to a different definition for that phrase used in a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_change). Furthermore, ratios often have skewed distributions that might not be well represented by the standard deviation in the original scale.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with most of the points from Elsa12. To be able to test whether two measurements for the same individual are significantly different from one another, you would need repeated measurements absent treatment and absent any other changes. This would tell you how much random measurement error there is associated with the outcome and allow you to estimate whether two values differ by an amount greater than we would expect by chance alone.

As you can't do that, I would recommend the following:

Firstly, make an average conclusion for the sample using whatever test you prefer. i.e., on average, the duration participants can hold their breath significantly increases 1.7 fold.

Second, choose some cutoffs that make sense and say something like: 75% of respondents saw increases in their time by at least 20% (FI of at least 1.2). You could also report how many had FIs below one.

Thirdly, you could create a plot showing the range of FIs across the sample. This is essentially calculating and plotting a treatment effect for every individual and would show the reader how much variability there is in the effects of the program.

Finally, if you wanted to, you could take those individual treatment effects (FIs) and regress them on sample characteristics to see which characteristics predict stronger and weaker effects (treatment effect heterogeneity analysis).

Hope some of that is helpful!

Comment: For reasons set forth in a comment to the question, I believe this answer misinterprets the question.

Answer (score 0):

I you are trying to determine whether subject X's duration improved significantly relative to their own baseline pre-test duration, the simple answer is that you cannot. While technically the study should use a control group, but I digress. The simple reality is that scenario would be the same as conducting a pre-test post-test prospective analysis on a sample size of 1. As mentioned by others, if you wanted to determine if the treatment effects are significant for a single individual, you would need to do a repeated measures study with an adequate sample of observations before and after. In your scenario, you are determining if the expected values of the distributions are far enough apart to be significant enough.

Now if you are trying to determine what percentage of the post treatment obserivations are significantly different from the pre-treatment observations, that's as simply as counting the observations of $\mu_{x_2}$  that are $\ge \bar{\mu_{x_1}}+1.96\sigma$.

Now, just to be thorough, if you were simply trying to determine if a subject x's improvement was signifcantly greater than the expected value of the cohort, that is as simple as a doing a one sample z-test but using the individual's score instead of the sample mean and use the sample mean in place of teh population mean. I.e., use $\frac{x - \bar{x}}{\frac{S_x}{\sqrt{n}}}$ instead of $\frac{\bar{x} - \mu_x}{\frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt{n}}}$. In that instance you are using the post test sample as a population. In that instance, you don't need a large sample to generate a second mean because you're not trying to draw any inferences. This is how they determine percentile scores for standardized tests and the IQ test.

But for determining how many people's post treatment performance was significantly better than that same person's pre-treatment performance using post-hoc analysis simply isn't possible. To determine the answer to that question would require basically performing an interrupted time-series analysis or with the requisite number of observations before and after the treatment. Then doing that for the entirety of your study population (I wouldn't suggest a repeated-measures design for that even if there are multiple pre- and post-treatment observations because in time-series the time variable is a consistent interval, which about as close as one could reasonably get to a random sample of an individual's performance before and after treatment).